# Separate string into array and then filter it

Tags: arrays, swift, string, filter

I have a string that looks like this:

```
let str = "One;Two;Three;Four;Five"
```

How do I put every value in an `array`, so each value is separated with the **";"** sign.

I have tried to iterate but that does not feel right. Then I also want to filter the result, for example get all values that contains the letter **"o"**.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, use these native functions:

Start by importing `Foundation`, `UIKit` or `Cocoa` (usually `Foundation` is default).

1: Your string:

```
let str = "One;Two;Three;Four;Five"
```

2: Separate each value from the ; sign into an array:

```
let arr = str.components(separatedBy: ";") // ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
```

3: Filter the result:

```
let containsO = arr.filter({ $0.contains("o")}) // Two, Four
```

3: Filter the result localized and case insensitive

```
let caseSensativeO = arr.filter({ $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("o")}) // One, Two, Four
```

Comment: The OP might want also a caseInsensitive search `let containsO = arr.filter({ $0.range(of: "o", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil })`

Comment: You'll need to `import Foundation` (or `UIKit` or `Cocoa`) for that to work.

Comment: or localizedCaseInsensitiveContains `let containsO = arr.filter({ $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("o") })`